# How to load JS-libraries only once in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

How can I archive loading a JS-library only once for multiples HTML pages in Phonegap.

I have this project:

```
./index.html

./FoderA/index.html

./FoderB/index.html
....
```

and in each index.html I use cordova2.2.0.js, but performance is reduced a little.
Can I load JS libs (cordova, jquerymobile, ....) once , for example when `./index.html` app starts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you navigate to a new page you'll need to reload all of your JavaScript so the way to avoid this is not to navigate to a new page. You can accomplish this buy using Ajax to load the second page and add it to your DOM. Take a look at this [good write up](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=en) where Bryce rolls his own loadPage functionality.

Other JavaScript frameworks like [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html) and Dojo allow you to do this as well albiet you need to load those frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this framework](http://cordova.codeplex.com). Below is the sample index.html from one of my projects:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Dark Maze</title>
<script src="Scripts/cordova/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Scripts/novas/nova.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/maze/maze.data.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="themes">
    <link href="themes/nova.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="themes/nova.ui.content.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</div>
<div id="body">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            nova.application.start("home.html");
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actually, all your other pages will be loaded into div#body via ajax calls. The other pages don't need to include <head> or <body>, only starting from <div>

The home.html:

```
<style>
#content {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.content-w1 {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.content-w1 h1 {
    background-color: #FFFCE5;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: #30C5F2;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

</style>

<div id="content">
<div class="content-w1">
    <div class="logo-home"></div>
    <ul class="color-blocks">
        <li>Never</li>
        <li>Lose</li>
        <li>Your</li>
        <li>Hope</li>
        <li>.</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="linkLevels">Choose Level</li>
        <li id="linkHelp">Help</li>
        <li id="linkQuickStart">
            Quick Start
            <small id="quickstartLevel">Level 1</small>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="challenge">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="links">
    &copy;2012, NovaSoftware.com, 
    <i>v1.0</i>
</div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


nova.application.currentPage.onLoaded(function () {
    function init() {
        if (window.DbService == undefined) {
            return;
        }

        var service = new DbService();
        var quickStart = 1;
        service.init(function () {
            service.getQuickStartLevel(function (level) {
                $("#quickstartLevel").html("Level " + level);
                quickStart = level;
            });
        });

        nova.touch.bindClick("#linkQuickStart", function () {
            alert("linkQuickStart");
            var page = new nova.Page("pages/game.html");
            page.level = quickStart;
            nova.application.gotoPage(page);
        });
        nova.touch.bindClick("#linkLevels", function () {
            nova.application.gotoPage("pages/levels.html");
        });
        //nova.application.gotoPage("pages/levels.html");
    }

    init();
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Ajax to load all js libraries and css to DOM